# Django: Just started learning django should i use django or jinja2 templates

Tags: python, django, templates, jinja2

I have just started learning django (with some non web python experience). I see there are at least two templates engines: default django and jinja2.

I see they are quite similar about syntax.

Which one i better for beginner?
which one is more perspective?

Many thanks,

Tomasz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion is to use the built-in one. This way you'll save some time at the beginning having a possibility to learn Django internals first.

Comment: Using the buit-in one has the avantage of better documentation and a lot of answeres/responses in stackoverflow and much more content on the web :)

Comment: Simple and powerful answers, Thank you Igor & Ninja

Answer (score 0):

If you have previously worked with Django templates, you should find Jinja2 very familiar. In fact, most of the syntax elements look and work the same.

but in some time ...

In django `{% ifequal foo "bar" %}` but ifequal will not work in jinja ...

You can find what are the differences in `switching`